# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

English Language Learners' [third moderator election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: MOD1_NAME]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5633995236704256).

Comment: Apparently [one of the nominees from the 1st election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-65543) just got a diamond too :-P

Comment: Congrats Em. and good luck for the next time Nathan!

Comment: Congratulations, Em!

Comment: Congratulations Em. Welcome to the group. Let's make this holy place better. :)

Comment: Catija - First post as CM, yay! So does this mean you're gonna post election results from now on?

Comment: @NathanTuggy - As a footnote to your gracious comment, I'd like to add: your "non-diamond moderation activities" will always be greatly appreciated by the mod team.

Comment: Thank you all, and congratulations to Catija on her new role and journey with SE. I'm excited for this opportunity and I'll do my best to help keep this a great resource for learning English.

Comment: I think many election commissions are now debating whether corgis constitute an "unfair advantage"  :)